# Habaneros....and bananas?

Tags: chili-peppers, marinade, spicy-hot, heat, bananas

I once marinated chicken breasts for the grill using some habaneros for heat and bananas for sweetness (and some vinegar and salt thrown in to cut some of the sweetness). To everyone's surprise, the bananas actually cut the heat of the peppers to the point where it was mild-to-medium...quite tolerable and delicious. I know it was the bananas because we have tried it other times with the same results. The question: what is it about bananas that cuts the heat of peppers? I once thought it was the fat content of bananas until I found out they are low in fat. Has anyone had similar experiences with bananas and hot peppers?

Comment: Bananas are starchy and absorbent, just as potatoes, squashes and other vegetables that can take quite some spice are....

Comment: rackandboneman--never thought about it that way!  Thanks!

Comment: Also... unripe plantain (these giant cooking bananas that are like potatoes when yellow and ripe when black) is commonly found in spicy south/southeast asian dishes...

Comment: There are banana peppers.  You should clarity in the question.  I thought you were asking about banana peppers until I read the comments.

Answer (score 1):

I found a [reference](https://www.wikihow.com/Cool-Burns-from-Chili-Peppers) searching on how to cool your mouth after eating a pepper.

> Eat starches. Eat starches if your mouth is burning from ingesting
> chili peppers. They should give you some relief.
>
> - Although starches
>   like rice and bread aren’t going to be as effective at dissolving the
>   capsaicin as fats, oils or alcohol, they will help cool the burn.
> - There is a reason that many cultures serve spicy food alongside white
>   rice (or potatoes). This is common in many Asian and Indian cultures.

According to this starched dissolve some of the capsaicin.

Personally I would skip the banana and go for a less hot pepper.  You are using one the hotter peppers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you came up with the solution (pun intended) when you added the vinegar (acid)and salt. Vinegar is often used to tone down the heat of peppers either before cooking, or during. I learned this from a pepper grower in the Yakima Valley in Washington state that grew over 300 types of peppers. I believe that was the reason for the reduced heat level. Limes have a similar effect.